# Convert URL to other affiliate URL using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have sample code below. When User add affid and URL then they can convert the URL to specific format.

```
Affid
<input type="text" id="affid">
URL    
<input type="text" id="url">
<button id="convert">Convert</button><br>
    <hr>
        <h4>output</h4>
    <input type="text" id="output"> <button id="select">Select</button>

        <br>
        <strong>Input:</strong> http://www.flipkart.com/asus-zenfone-4-a400cg/p/itmeygpv4uxt4gjx?pid=MOBDXZ9WQFBAY2XX<br>
        <strong>Output:</strong> http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/asus-zenfone-4-a400cg/p/itmeygpv4uxt4gjx?pid=MOBDXZ9WQFBAY2XX&affid=waz<br>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/we070pgL/)

If user enters **affId** *waz* and **url** *http://www.flipkart.com/asus-zenfone-4-a400cg/p/itmeygpv4uxt4gjx?pid=MOBDXZ9WQFBAY2XX*

Output should be 
*http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/asus-zenfone-4-a400cg/p/itmeygpv4uxt4gjx?pid=MOBDXZ9WQFBAY2XX&affid=waz*

Comment: What is expected input/output?

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle link?

Comment: Updated links.. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/we070pgL/1/

From your fiddle I have assumed you will use jQuery. In case you don't want jQuery, you will only need to change the jQuery selectors to `getElementById()`

**Function to take the fields and manipulate and display in output box**

```
function ConvertURL(){
var URL = $("#url").val();
var Affid = $("#affid").val();

URL = URL.replace("www","dl");

var position = URL.indexOf(".com");    
URL = [URL.slice(0, position+5), "dl/", URL.slice(position+5)].join('');

var convertedURL = URL+"&affid="+Affid;

$("#output").val(convertedURL);
}
```

**Change in HTML**

```
<button id="convert" onclick="ConvertURL()">
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please be a little clearer in your questions henceforth. Took some time to figure out what you wanted!